# Ajax Set-Cookie Header Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a project which using a a REST API. Here when I send a login request, they are sending me the response as JSON containg some data. Along with that in Response Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:private
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:49
Date:Sun, 28 Jul 2013 08:09:29 GMT
ntCoent-Length:36
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=044F94AFE2997F02475315474E3B822D; Path=/
Set-Cookie:NSC_Ibgja-IUUQt=ffffffffc3a0b60545525d5f4f58455e445a4a4229a0;expires=Sun, 28-Jul-2013 08:55:40 GMT;path=/;secure
X-Powered-By:Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.2.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_2_GA
```

Here we have a Set-Cookie , but this cookie is not setting. I need this cookie to be setted, because for any other API access, the server will check for this cookie.

How can I resolve this Issue? What is the solution for jQuery AJAX response Header Set-Cookie method?

Update:

the first ajax for login

```
    var json='{"nin":"'+1080258278+'","password":"'+840622+'"}';
var hostURL = "https://www.hafiz.gov.sa";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: hostURL + "/HRDFWeb/AuthenticateDirectly",
    data: "json="+json+"&date="+Number(new Date()),
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 180000, // in milliseconds
    success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){

        console.log(data);
   },
    error: function(request, status, err) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know the Cookie isn't being set? How are you accessing the API?

Comment: there are 2 `Set-Cookie` which would cause problems.

Comment: @Khanh not really, seeing as they're for different cookie names

Comment: @Pekka 웃: even they're for different cookie keys, we should combine into 1 `Set-Cookie` only. Otherwise, the cookie will be expired immediately (I had this problem in the past with IE).

Comment: @Pekka웃 document.cookie has not values, i have 2 ajax call: 1 for login, and 1 for getting infomations.

when i login, server return this reponse header

Comment: @KhanhTO i checked with Chrome and FireFox

Comment: I can't access to server, how can i resolve this issue

Comment: @Khanh it seems to be generally accepted and acceptable practice to send multiple cookie headers - even though it's not perfect and cookies should ideally be grouped in one header. See e.g. http://kristol.org/cookie/errata.html#multi-header

Comment: @Anh can you show some more code? Are the cookies present the next time you open the page?

Comment: @Pekka웃 i will update the question

Comment: I guess you run into timing problem with ajax (because ajax is asyn). If you send the first ajax for login and send the second ajax right after that, the response of the first ajax (including Set-Cookie) may not arrive yet and the cookie is not set.

Comment: @KhanhTO i updated the question, i think it is related to this link https://drupal.org/node/1133084

Comment: Are you on `https://www.hafiz.gov.sa` when you are making this call? Remember, Ajax requests can't generally go outside their domain. Are you getting data back from the call? The Drupal bug you mention doesn't apply, it's about sending Cookie headers *from client side*

Comment: @Pekka웃 it's remote server, i make a cross-domain ajax request. I think the Response Header will set cookie for domain "www.hafiz.gov.sa" but because of some policy, this action is not success

Comment: I don't think that is going to work in the form you show above. See [JQuery ajax cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3506208)

Comment: @Pekka웃 i updated the question, you can run it, it work now

Comment: Really? That would seem weird, as you would still hit the cross-domain barrier. So it works for you now, problem solved?

Comment: no sir, when i call the second ajax, because  the server will check for this cookie so it fail